# How do I identify duplicate nodes in XPath 1.0 using an XPathNavigator to evaluate?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xpath

I am trying to identify duplicate serial numbers from the following xml using XPath 1.0 and then evaluating it in .Net using an `XPathNavigator`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Inventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>1112</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>1112</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Inventory>
```

I tried to do this by evaluating this

```
//Items/Item/SerialNumber
```

expression in a custom XSLT Context Function (implementing `IXsltContextFunction` [like this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715)) in .Net but the Invoke function gets called one result at a time so I have no visibility of the other results to find duplicates.

**1) Is there a way of doing this using a single XPath 1.0 expression?**

OR

**2) Is there a way of passing in an array of elements into a single Invoke call of the custom XSLT Context Function class?** I'm working in VB.Net but am happy with any C# examples anyone can share.

Thanks,

Gavin

**Edit**

Thanks to O R Mapper and Dimitre for their responses. I initially accepted O R Mapper's response since it did do what I asked. I've since accepted Dimitre's answer since I like  that it provides a distinct list of values. Both responses very helpful though!

Comment: Gavin Sutherland: Are you aware that the currently accepted answer is incorrect? For the provided XML document it selects a single node. However, if there are more than two elements with the same string value (let's say three or more `<SerialNumber>1112</SerialNumber>`), then the XPath expression selects every duplicate, with the exception of the first. So, if there are 10 elements `<SerialNumber>1112</SerialNumber>` the expression selects nine text nodes "1112". It seems to me, that you want only one "1112" text node to be selected.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: The question asks for how to find serial numbers that are duplicates. So, if there are 10 elements `<SerialNumber>1112</SerialNumber>`, then 9 of those elements are duplicates. Hence, the originally accepted answer was exactly what was asked for. The question doesn't say what is going to happen with the respective nodes, so there is no reason to automatically assume the OP doesn't want a complete list of duplicate nodes occurring in the document.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Yes, this is why in my comment I asked if my guess were right -- turns out I was... In my experience, "realworld" questions, more often than not, mean something different than they are saying -- and we need to live with that fact and adapt. Developing one's guessing power isn't something bad, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/Item
      [SerialNumber = following-sibling::Item/SerialNumber
     and
       not(SerialNumber = preceding-sibling::Item/SerialNumber)
      ]
```

This selects just one `Item` element for any group of `Item` elements that have a `SerialNumber` child with the same string value.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/*/*/Item
          [SerialNumber = following-sibling::Item/SerialNumber
         and
           not(SerialNumber = preceding-sibling::Item/SerialNumber)
          ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document** (based on the provided one, but made more interesting):

```
<Inventory>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <SerialNumber>3333</SerialNumber>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Inventory>
```

**the transformation evaluates the XPath expression and copies the selected nodes to the output:**

```
<Item>
   <SerialNumber>1111</SerialNumber>
</Item>
<Item>
   <SerialNumber>2222</SerialNumber>
</Item>
```

**Finally, if you want to get just the `SerialNumber` duplicate values, use**:

```
   /*/*/Item
          [SerialNumber = following-sibling::Item/SerialNumber
         and
           not(SerialNumber = preceding-sibling::Item/SerialNumber)
          ]
           /SerialNumber/text()
```

Comment: Excellent answer @Dimitre. Does the initial /*/*/ represent the Inventory and Items nodes?

Comment: @GavinSutherland: Yes, because we know the structure of the XML document, we know that only/exactly these elements can be selected by `/*/*` -- this is a convenient shortcut and is slightly more efficient that an exact name test.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm going to answer **1)**, so **2)** should not matter any more:*

You can use the `preceding-sibling` axis on your `<Item>` elements to find any preceding `<Item>` elements with the same serial number.

Try this (written so that it returns only the serial numbers themselves rather than elements - if this is not quite what you want, and you don't know how to change the result, let me know):

```
/Inventory/Items/Item/SerialNumber/node()[.=../../preceding-sibling::Item/SerialNumber/node()]
```

For your sample document, it returns

```
1112
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Does what I need. Thank you!