# Identify Duplicate Nodes in XML Using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to identify duplicate group nodes in the following XML structure.
I need to find all groups with the same name, wherever they are in the tree.

```
<report>
    <group name="a">
        <group name="1"></group>
        <group name="2"></group>
    </group>
    <group name="b">
        <group name="1"></group>
    </group>
</report>
```

Similar to this post ([How do I identify duplicate nodes in XPath 1.0 using an XPathNavigator to evaluate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203117/how-do-i-identify-duplicate-nodes-in-xpath-1-0-using-an-xpathnavigator-to-evalua))
However, I need to identify groups with the same attribute rather than the same node value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using Linq To xml to find duplicates?

```
var dubs = XDocument.Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("group")
            .GroupBy(g => (string)g.Attribute("name"))
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: That is some wierd looking XPath :-) didnt OP ask specific for XPath ?

Comment: @JensKloster So? Is *showing other alternatives* to OP and other S.O users is a bad thing? Isn't it possible that OP asks for XPath because the sample he uses utilizes XPath. Maybe he is open also to Linq

Comment: notes how I have not downvoted your answer. I to, would prefer Linq :-) when I saw your answer I thought - he didnt even Read the question. Properly because you just posted a code block.

Answer (score 5):

The solution to your problem is very similar to the one in the answer you linked, but you need to address an attribute instead of child element and want to search for all following and sibling nodes, not only among siblings.

---

Look for all groups that have a name which you find again afterwards, but not before.

```
//group[@name = following::group/@name and not(@name = preceding::group/@name)]
```

If you want all occurrences, search in both directions instead:

```
//group[@name = following::group/@name or @name = preceding::group/@name]
```

Comment: this is not working for me, so i went with the solution below. thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the input you provided the exact same like you use? Most often it is a problem with namespaces which prevent simply queries like that from running.