# How to find a duplicate attribute value in xml using XPATH

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<RootNode>
    <innerNode name="x1"/>
    <innerNode name="x2"/>
    <innerNode name="x1"/>
    <innerNode name="x3"/>
</RootNode>
```

How can I find , using XPATH, and without iterating over the result, innerNode with duplicate name? (in above example, x1 is duplicate).

Comment: You really need to specify XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more comprehensive solution, adapted from an [answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16468263/4469405):

```
//innerNode[
    @name = following::innerNode/@name
       or 
    @name = preceding::innerNode/@name
]
```

This will find duplicates even in case of nested `innerNode` elements like below:

```
<RootNode>
    <innerNode name="x1">
        <innerNode name="x1" />
        <innerNode name="x2" />
    </innerNode>
    <innerNode name="x2">
        <innerNode name="x3" />
    </innerNode>
</RootNode>
```

**EDIT:** As a further generalization, to find the `name` attribute **anywhere** inside `innerNode`s:

```
//innerNode[
    descendant-or-self::*/@name = following::innerNode/descendant-or-self::*/@name
        or 
    descendant-or-self::*/@name = preceding::innerNode/descendant-or-self::*/@name
]
```

This will find the `name` attribute from `childNode` of first `innerNode` to be equal with the `name` attribute from last (i.e. the 3rd) `innerNode` itself:

```
<RootNode>
    <innerNode>
        <childNode name="x1" />
    </innerNode>
    <innerNode>
        <childNode name="x2" />
    </innerNode>
    <innerNode name="x1"/>
</RootNode>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following XPath will return `innerNode` elements where `name` attribute has duplicate in sibling `innerNode` elements :

```
//innerNode[
    @name = following-sibling::innerNode/@name
        or
    @name = preceding-sibling::innerNode/@name
]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/uDwe8G-2X)</kbd>**