# is there an xpath statement to disambiguate 2 elements with the same name, but different attributes?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have an xml file containing typedef enums and plain enums with the same name element. I want to disambiguate them by an attribute using an xpath statement. I must use xpath1.0.

I've tried several existing answers in SO, but none seem to answer my disambiguation question. Example:
[How do I identify duplicate nodes in XPath 1.0 using an XPathNavigator to evaluate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203117/how-do-i-identify-duplicate-nodes-in-xpath-1-0-using-an-xpathnavigator-to-evalua)

I tried the below statement hoping to just eliminate the dupes, but it doesn't seem to work and wouldn't disambiguate the nodes anyway:

```
/*/*/member[name = following-sibling::member/name and not(name = preceding-sibling::member/name)]
```

Sample of my xml:

```
<member kind="enum"><name>myEnum</name></member>
<member kind="typedef"><name>myEnum></name></member>
```

Desired result:
When name elements are duplicated I want to extract the typedef enum and not the plain enum.

Answer (score 0):

For example:
If you take the following XML as input file

```
<a class="my-class">
    <c>
        <member kind="enum">
            <name>myEnum111</name>
        </member>
        <member kind="typedef">
            <name>myEnum444></name>
        </member>
    </c>
    <d>
        <member kind="enum">
            <name>myEnum222</name>
        </member>
    </d>
    <d>
        <member kind="whatever">
            <name>myEnum666</name>
        </member>
        <member kind="else">
            <name>myEnum777</name>
        </member>
        <member kind="typedef">
            <name>myEnum000</name>
        </member>
        <member kind="itmaybe">
            <name>myEnum999</name>
        </member>
    </d>
</a>
```

and the following as XPath-1.0 expression

```
/*/*/member[(count(../member) = 1 and contains(name,'myEnum')) or (count(../member) > 1 and @kind='typedef')]
```

it will give you this (correct) output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<member kind="typedef">
    <name>myEnum444&gt;</name>
</member>
<member kind="enum">
    <name>myEnum222</name>
</member>
<member kind="typedef">
    <name>myEnum000</name>
</member>
```

This is the desired output as stated by

> [...] When name elements are duplicated I want to extract the `typedef` enum and not the plain enum.

The behavior if there are more than one `typedef` attribute nodes is undefined (It (probably) returns the first one).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I should have made it clear that I don't know the names of the enums, there are thousands of them in the file. I need a statement that will find dupes, disambiguate them with the kind attribute, and return only the typedefs.

Comment: @user1413622: Glad I could help. BTW saying thanks for a solution is usually expressed by clicking the "Accepted Answer" symbol on the upper left side of the answer ;-)